# SQL: break column into multiple columns by cell value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I'm trying to build a module in VBA that will query 2 data sources and left join them on the common field of "Name". The problem is that the data are grained differently. The set I'm trying to change currently looks like this:

[image: current]

And I'm trying to make it look like this:

[image: desired]

So that I can left join it with a query from my second dataset, which is grained by "name" rather than "item value".

FWIW, here's what the query I'm currently trying to run looks like. I'm using an implicit join to get "current value" and "past value" for each "name", but none of this refers to dataset 2:

```
with set1 as (SELECT NAME, ITEM_CODE, ITEM_VALUE_NUMBER as CURRENT_VALUE FROM [...] WHERE [...]),
with set2 as (SELECT NAME, ITEM_CODE, ITEM_VALUE_NUMBER as PAST_VALUE FROM [...] WHERE [...]),
SELECT set1.NAME [ITEM_1], [ITEM_2], [ITEM_3] from
(SELECT set1.NAME, set1.CURRENT_VALUE, set2.PAST_VALUE FROM set1, set2 WHERE set1.NAME=set2.NAME and set1.ITEM_CODE=set2.ITEM_CODE) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (max(CURRENT_VALUE) for ITEM_CODE in [ITEM_1], [ITEM_2], [ITEM_3]) AS PivotTable;
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a couple options. First is trying to reword the pivot to get the results you want, which makes for a more complicated query than required. You can do this in the following way if you wish:

```
SELECT Name
     , MAX(C1) Item1CurrentValue
     , MAX(P1) Item1PastValue
     , MAX(C2) Item2CurrentValue
     , MAX(P2) Item2PastValue
     , MAX(C3) Item3CurrentValue
     , MAX(P3) Item3PastValue
FROM (
    SELECT set1.Name
         , 'C' + CAST(set1.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(255)) ItemCode1
         , CurVal
         , 'P' + CAST(set2.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(255)) ItemCode2
         , PastVal
    FROM (SELECT Name, ItemCode, ITEM_VALUE_NUMBER CurVal FROM myFirstQuery) set1
    JOIN (SELECT Name, ItemCode, ITEM_VALUE_NUMBER PastVal FROM mySecondQuery) set2 ON set1.Name = set2.Name AND set1.ItemCode = set2.ItemCode) T
PIVOT (MAX(CurVal) FOR ItemCode1 IN (C1, C2, C3)) P1
PIVOT (MAX(PastVal) FOR ItemCode2 IN (P1, P2, P3)) P2
GROUP BY Name;
```

I don't really think CTEs make the query more readable so I just removed them, but you could use the CTEs in a similar fashion if you wish.

The better (and easier to understand, in my opinion) way is to just use conditional aggregation, like such:

```
SELECT Name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ItemCode = 1 THEN CurVal END) Item1CurrentValue
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ItemCode = 1 THEN PastVal END) Item1PastValue
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ItemCode = 2 THEN CurVal END) Item2CurrentValue
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ItemCode = 2 THEN PastVal END) Item2PastValue
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ItemCode = 3 THEN CurVal END) Item3CurrentValue
     , MAX(CASE WHEN ItemCode = 3 THEN PastVal END) Item3PastValue
FROM (
    SELECT set1.Name
         , set1.ItemCode
         , CurVal
         , PastVal
    FROM (SELECT Name, ItemCode, ITEM_VALUE_NUMBER CurVal FROM myFirstQuery) set1
    JOIN (SELECT Name, ItemCode, ITEM_VALUE_NUMBER PastVal FROM mySecondQuery) set2 ON set1.Name = set2.Name AND set1.ItemCode = set2.ItemCode) T
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up doing something much more crude: I declared six sets, one for each item current/past, then left joined set2 to set1, set3 to set2, etc. Would have loved to get a query in the mold you suggested working for me (I just couldn't get it to work) but this will have to do for now.